# Refresh on views

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, refresh

I'm trying to refresh my views when I go from one to another. I know I should place the refresh code in viewWillAppear but I don't know what code to put.

Could you guys assist me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your view, call `setNeedsDisplay`. Usually though views are marked as needing to be redrawn automatically, so if this isn't solving your problem you might have another issue.

Comment: So I will have to do that on the logout?